# What are the differences between should, were, and if conditional clauses?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning, conditional-constructions

> Mr. Brocklehurst, I believe I intimated in the letter which I wrote to you three weeks ago, that this little girl has not quite the character and disposition I could wish: **should** you admit her into Lowood school, I should be glad if the superintendent and teachers were requested to keep a strict eye on her, and, above all, to guard against her worst fault, a tendency to deceit.
>   (Jane Eyre)

I guess *should* can be replaced by *were*, or *if*. What are the semantic differences between all three of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s a matter of degrees of formality. ‘Should you admit her . . .’, . ‘Were you to admit her . . .’ and ‘If you were to admit her . . . .’ are all particularly formal. The informal, and more usual, construction would be ‘If you admitted her . . .’

The sentence is basically an instance of what is sometimes taught to foreign learners of English as the Second Conditional. The differences in style can perhaps be better appreciated by stepping away from this example from nineteenth century fiction, and looking at a sentence that might occur in contemporary English. Suppose that I have a friend who wants to catch a train. I know that he could if he hurried, but I also know that he won’t, because he’s unfit. In those circumstances, I would normally say

> If you ran, you’d catch the train.

The three formal versions, equivalent to Charlotte Brontë’s sentence and the two 
alternatives I have proposed, are:

> Should you run you’d catch the train.
>
> Were you to run, you’d catch the train.
>
> If you were to run, you’d catch the train.

You will see that the degree of formality shown in these constructions would be quite inappropriate in the situation.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Jayne Eyre* sentence, "**should** you admit her into Lowood school, I **should** be glad if" can be rewritten as "{**if you** / **were you to**} accept her as a student in your school, I **will** be happy if..."

> *Whether* and *if* are usually interchangeable, as in. e.g., "I don't know {**whether / if**} she's sick or well".
>
> *Should* and *if* are usually interchangeable, as in. e.g., "{**Should / If**} you decide to accept our offer, please...". "**Were you to** decide to accept our offer, please..." is also possible, but it doesn't seem felicitous style to me.

You can check the semantic differences in a dictionary. In the examples I've given you, the differences are stylistic, not semantic. And each has different usage rules.

Comment: @mcalex: No. There's no syntactic difference between, eg, "I don't know whether" and "I don't know if", just a difference in the sound of the sentence because of the difference in the number of syllables. I'd say that "if" is in a slightly lower register than the slightly more formal "whether".

Comment: There is, however, a semantic difference between ‘Let us know if you’re coming to dinner’ and  ‘Let us know whether you’re coming to dinner.’

Comment: @Barrie: True, the dictionary implies that _whether_ asks for a _yes_ or a _no_ answer but _if_ asks only for a _yes_.  There's also a semantic difference between "**Fewer** people are here tonight" and "**Less** people are here tonight". In practice, however, most native speakers of English are either ignorant or disdainful of these semantic differences & use these pairs interchangeably, so descriptivists are not allowed to mention it in public: hypocrisy is hypocrisy. [Sometimes tautologies can be useful.]

Comment: There is indeed a difference between _fewer_ and _less_, and it is one of which I am sure many native speakers are aware. It ‘is essentially a stylistic choice between the more formal **fewer** and the more spontaneous **less**.  **Fewer** draws attention to itself, whereas **less** shifts the focus on to its more significant neighbours.' (‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’)

Comment: @Barrie: And this is exactly why I dislike the _CGEL_ & its hypocritical authors. I don't believe that Geoffrey Pullum says or writes "Less people are here tonight".

Comment: The author of ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage' is Pam Peters, Emeritus Professor of Linguistics at Macquarie University, Sydney.

Comment: @Barrie: Oh, sorry. I misread the title. I still don't believe what she says, though. It's merely a descriptivist rationalization. I don't suppose they're any more palatable than prescriptivist lies, though.

Answer (score 1):

In other contexts, should can carry a connotation of obligation, but that isn't at issue here.  Essentially, in this context there is real no semantic difference.

There is a syntactic difference in the follow-on words in the sentence that relate to 'should', if it is changed - to illustrate:

> **should** you admit her into Lowood school, I **should** be glad if the superintendent and teachers **were** requested to keep a strict eye on her ...

> **were** you **to** admit her into Lowood school, I **would** be glad if the superintendent and teachers were requested to keep a strict eye on her ...

> **if** you admit her into Lowood school, I **will** be glad if the superintendent and teachers **are** requested to keep a strict eye on her ...

Even though this suggests that the *should* and *were* versions are past tense, in the context, they are all future tense, but Ms Brontë is using a future event as though it had already happened